# Replace 2009 Cobalt LNF Fuel Tank Pressure Sensor and Shroud

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-system, sensor, cobalt, evap

How difficult is it to replace the fuel tank pressure sensor and shroud on a 2009 Chevrolet Cobalt (LNF/SS)?

The shop just quoted me over $200 for this. From what I can tell, the parts should be about $45 retail.

How much labor is involved?

Do the shops actually pay a higher price?

Is this something that I can do myself fairly easily?

Is there a good service guide/manual for my car?

Comment: It should be noted here that "LNF" is just the GM three digit engine code for the Cobalt, nothing more. Don't think it's a "Life's Not Fair" acronym ;-)